# Applying function within a user-defined function to round off

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to roundup numbers that satisfy a condition and round down numbers that satisfy a different condition. I wrote the below function to do this, but there seems to be a problem with it.

```
Range   New Range     I/D         Expected output
1         1.1         Increase       2
1         1.4         Increase       2
1         .7          Decrease       0
1         .9          Decrease       0
3         2.2         No Change      2
5         4.8         No Change      5
```

Basically if there's a flag to increase, apply the function to round up; a flag to decrease would mean apply the function to round down; and no flag would be a basic roundoff.

```
def inc(row):
    if row['increae']=='increase':
        val= row['Final New Range'].apply(np.ceil)
    elif row['increae']=='increase':
        val= row['Final New Range'].apply(np.ceil)
    else:
        val='None'
    return val
```

Traceback

```
<ipython-input-35-8f7b70f1c7f8> in inc(row)
     17 def inc(row):
     18     if row['increae']=='increase':
---> 19         val= row['Final New Range'].apply(np.ceil)
     20     elif row['increae']=='increase':
     21         val= row['Final New Range'].apply(np.ceil)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide sample df along with your explanation and expected output to improve your chances of getting a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want would be something like this:

```
def inc(row):
    if row['increae']=='Increase':
        return int( np.ceil(row["New Range"]) )
    elif row['increae']=='Decrease':
        return int( np.floor(row["New Range"]) )
    else:
        return int( np.round(row["New Range"]) )
```

Run this piece of code to test it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def inc(row):
    if row['increae']=='Increase':
        return int( np.ceil(row["New Range"]) )
    elif row['increae']=='Decrease':
        return int( np.floor(row["New Range"]) )
    else:
        return int( np.round(row["New Range"]) )

# Example of use

# Sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.1, "Increase"], 
                   [1, 1.4, "Increase"],
                   [1, 0.7, "Decrease"],
                   [1, 0.9, "Decrease"],
                   [3, 2.2, "No Change"],
                   [5, 4.8, "No Change"],
                   ]
                  , columns=['Range', 'New Range', 'increae']) # column names

# Iterating through the rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():   
    print(row[0], row[1], row[2], "--> output", inc(row) )
```

`inc(row)` gets the result for each row

Output of running that:

```
1 1.1 Increase --> output 2
1 1.4 Increase --> output 2
1 0.7 Decrease --> output 0
1 0.9 Decrease --> output 0
3 2.2 No Change --> output 2
5 4.8 No Change --> output 5
```

This should work for you if you change the column names for whatever you have in your original dataframe.